# OmniFaces 1.8.1 SEVERE: WebXml failed to initialize. Perhaps your web.xml contains a typo?

Tags: jsf, web.xml, omnifaces

I am trying to install OmniFaces in my project. I put `omnifaces-1.8.1.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and implement [FacesViews](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) configuration in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, during deploy I get the exception below:

```
SEVERE: WebXml failed to initialize. Perhaps your web.xml contains a typo?
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.parseErrorPageLocations(WebXml.java:434)
        at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:147)
        at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener.contextInitialized(FacesViewsInitializerListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Oct 09, 2014 9:48:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.java.io.IOException
        at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:156)
        at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener.contextInitialized(FacesViewsInitializerListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.parseErrorPageLocations(WebXml.java:434)
        at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:147)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: I think it should be ```*.xhtml``` insted of ```/*.xhtml```

Comment: no even if i remove / the same problem raise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.parseErrorPageLocations(WebXml.java:434)
```

You apparently have a:

```xml
<exception-type>java.lang.java.io.IOException</exception-type>
```

That exception class indeed doesn't exist. Fix it accordingly:

```xml
<exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
```

Your `web.xml` definitely contained a typo.

Comment: great Mr.balusc, can you explain what is the meaning of typo